# Disable Main Window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am working on WPF application where I am running a scan function in the main window. The scan section is running in a separate thread. After scan terminates, it shows another window as a modal popup.

Now, What I exactly want is to disable the main window when the popup comes out after the scan gets completed. So, the user cannot click on the main window until he closes the popup. But I am unable to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Is popup a window? Can you show the relevant code? If its a window, Can't you call `ShowDialog` on it?

Comment: "it shows another window as a modal popup" How can you access main window when some other modal window is showing?

Comment: I am using the ShowDialog but its not working accordingly.

if (!Licensed.ValidateLicenseKey(ScanAreas.LicenseKey) && scanStatus == "complete")
 {                    
                    ModalPopup popup = new ModalPopup();                    
                    popup.Activate();
                    popup.Topmost = true;
                    popup.ShowDialog();

                }

this is the code

Answer (score 2):

Set parent window as owner for child window (Popup) and open your child window as `Showdialog()` like below:

Create "`NavigationService.cs`" class and put the below code in this class.

```
public void ShowPopUpWindow(PopUpWindowViewModel popUpWindowViewModel)
       {
           PopUpWindowView= new PopUpWindowView();
           PopUpWindowView.DataContext = popUpWindowViewModel;
           PopUpWindowView.Owner = ParentWindowView;
           PopUpWindowView.ShowDialog();
       }
```

Now, call the above method in your `ViewModel` class like below:

```
PopUpWindowViewModel popUpWindowViewModel = new PopUpWindowViewModel ();
PopUpWindowViewModel.Name = "This is Popup Window";
NavigationService navigationService = new NavigationService();
navigationService.ShowPopUpWindow(PopUpWindowViewModel);
```

It will not let you to click on parent window until you close the child window.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that reading the [Dialog Boxes Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN will clear up your confusion. From the linked page:

> A modal dialog box is displayed by a function when the function needs additional data from a user to continue. Because the function depends on the modal dialog box to gather data, the modal dialog box also prevents a user from activating other windows in the application while it remains open. In most cases, a modal dialog box allows a user to signal when they have finished with the modal dialog box by pressing either an OK or Cancel button. Pressing the OK button indicates that a user has entered data and wants the function to continue processing with that data. Pressing the Cancel button indicates that a user wants to stop the function from executing altogether. The most common examples of modal dialog boxes are shown to open, save, and print data.

Please read the *Creating a Modal Custom Dialog Box* section on the linked page to find out how to create your own custom modal dialog `Window`.

---

UPDATE >>>

A very simple alternative is to add an element that will overlay all other elements on the page:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Your content here -->  
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
         Fill="#3FFFFFFF" Visibility="{Binding IsOverlayVisible, 
         Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Of course, you'll need to data bind a `bool` property (`IsOverlayVisible`) using a `IValueConverter` to control when it's displayed.

Comment: Actually it's not a modal popup its another wpf window.I just gave name the window as ModalWindow. This thing is working fine if i open another window and show it as ShowDialog. But the problem comes when it opens after the scan got finished because the scan method is written under another thread than Main UI thread.

Comment: According your description `user can not click on the main window untill he close the popup` it is modal dialog. ShowDialog does exactly this.

Comment: Yes this thing is working fine but only when we open that window outside the thread section. When same window is used inside other thread at that point of time the main window gets enabled and showdialog is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use current `Dispatcher` object for calling `ShowDialog`.

use following block in your code which you are executing in some other thread.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    //Show your dialog here.

}));
```